# magento 2 is the position of parent::costruct() relevant?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, construct

I'm looking at Magento 2 core code. When Magento needs to extend a class, it creates a class with a constructor that calls the parent construct via the `parent::__construct()` method, something like this:

```
class B extends A
{
  protected $otherclass;

  public function __construct(
    ParentClass $parentclass,
    \Vendor\Module\Folder\OtherClass $otherclass
  ) {
    parent::__construct($parentclass);
    $this->otherclass = $otherclass;
  }
}
```

In some cases, `parent::__construct()` is at the beginning of the constructor (as in the example), in other cases it's at the end:

```
class B extends A
{
  protected $otherclass;

  public function __construct(
    ParentClass $parentclass,
    \Vendor\Module\Folder\OtherClass $otherclass
  ) {
    $this->otherclass = $otherclass;
    parent::__construct($parentclass);
  }
}
```

Is there a reason for `parent::__construct()` to be in different positions? If so, in which cases should it go at the beginning and when at the end?